# Algorithm Downheap

Tags: heap

For the downheap function, we normally compare the two children values at first, determine which one is smaller, and compare the parent value with the smaller child's value, and at last switch. 
But what if I just compare the parent value to the left child, if bigger, switch. And compare the right child, if bigger, switch.
Will this work?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c++` ?

Comment: No idea - there's no C++ code to be seen. Untagged.

Answer (score 0):

As long as each parent is smaller than its children - it will work. Note that in your case you may be making two switches. Each switch requires you to compare the new parent to its children (the grandchildren of the original parent). So you'd better make one switch and not two.